# Pandoc failed to compile on GHC 7.8.2

Tags: haskell, fedora, ghc, pandoc

I tried to install *Pandoc* on *GHC-7.8.2*, *Fedora 19* and got problem with *zip-archive* package.

> zip-archive-0.2.2.1 failed during the building phase.
>
> The exception was: ExitFailure 1

So I get last one from github, and tried to install it from sources and still getting errors:

```
Preprocessing library zip-archive-0.2.2.1...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSzlib-0.5.4.1-ghc7.8.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStext-1.1.1.2-ghc7.8.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSmtl-2.2.0.1-ghc7.8.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStransformers-0.4.1.0-ghc7.8.2
```

I have zlib, zlib,-devel, ghc-zlib, ghc-zlib-devel already installed

**Update:**

I finally get rid of this problem after manual replacement of my */usr/bin/cabal* executable with newer 1.20, built by root, but encountered with another one:

```
[ 5 of 57] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.Haddock.Lex ( dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Haddock/Lex.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Haddock/Lex.o )

dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Haddock/Lex.hs:500:17:
    Pattern bindings containing unlifted types should use an outermost bang pattern:

...

dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Haddock/Lex.hs:504:31:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Int#’
    In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(offset >=# 0#)’
    In the expression: (offset >=# 0#) && (check ==# ord_c)
    In the expression:
      if (offset >=# 0#) && (check ==# ord_c) then
          alexIndexInt16OffAddr alex_table offset
      else
          alexIndexInt16OffAddr alex_deflt s

dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Haddock/Lex.hs:504:50:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Int#’
    In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(check ==# ord_c)’
    In the expression: (offset >=# 0#) && (check ==# ord_c)
    In the expression:
      if (offset >=# 0#) && (check ==# ord_c) then
          alexIndexInt16OffAddr alex_table offset
      else
          alexIndexInt16OffAddr alex_deflt s
Failed to install pandoc-1.12.4
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
pandoc-1.12.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
```

Reinstalling haddock didn't help.

***Any suggestions how to fix this?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the dynamic libraries. Most likely, you need to install cabal-install-1.18 or later, wipe our your package database, and install again. For more information, see: https://plus.google.com/115504368969270249241/posts/R8EYrABDrvv

Comment: Thank you, this helped a bit, but compilation problem still exists. See update.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an old version of alex installed. To be safe, try running `cabal install alex happy && cabal install pandoc`.

Comment: Michael is right. See http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-08-happy-alex-ghc-7.8.html

Comment: Thank you Michael, you helped me again! Indeed, this was problem with alex and happy.